# Everyone has two right hands

Tags: alternate-worlds

What would differ in a world where everyone has two right hands (i.e. the orientation of left hands is reversed)?

I'm most interested in how this would impact everyday life (social interactions, work and leisure etc).

Comment: Noone would have to suffer the pain of left handed scissors.

Comment: Welcome to the site! This is an interesting question, however, it is a bit too broad I'm afraid. There might be a lot of effects of right-handedness, but try to pick a smaller area. Are you talking about social interactions? Manufacturing? Military combat? Try to make this a little more specific. You can ask more than one question if you need to. Otherwise you end up with several good answers but no "best" or "correct" answer.

Comment: You can introduce yourself to people and shake their 2 hands :D

Answer (score 0):

We would constantly snag our left thumbs on things. The sinister people could use some dexterous equipment easier but not with it directly in front of them but off to the left. Although some things like bows would be much more awkward.

Steering wheels on cars would have to be redesigned or sharp turns would be harder to perform (for everybody).

Humans would no longer be symmetrical resulting in even more spinning in dance. Handholding would be too awkward to be a thing. The do-si-do soar in popularity.

It would be even easier to push-over (from the left) someone doing push-ups. Harder from the right.

The sinister-dexterous trope would be strengthened even though handedness would not be useable as a name for it. Most likely instead of right-handed left-handed we would say regular folks and inexplicably inept oafs. because inverted

I would suppose that left-handedness would be more strongly selected against and would disappear. Although it seems to be not strictly genetic.